# How to display specific JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays

Here is my json data :

```
var jsondata = 
[ { "month" : "01" },
  { "folders" : [ { "name" : "test1" },
        { "name" : "test2" },
        { "name" : "test3" }
      ] },
  { "actions" : [ { "id" : "2" },
        { "id" : "4" }
      ] }
]
```

I use `JSON.parse` in order to transform my json text into an json array (no problems here), and I want to display the month... but it dosen't work.. why ?

```
var JsonData = JSON.parse(jsondata);
var month = JsonData.month;
alert(month);
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposed to be

```
JsonData[0].month;
```

Your **json is an array of objects.** And `month` is the 1st item inside the Array. So to access the value for month, you would point it to the item inside the array and then try to get the value for that key.

If the json object was in this format then the notation that you have written would have worked.

```
var jsondata = { "month"  : "01",
                 "month1" : "02",
                 "month1" : "02" 
               }
```

One of the way might be

```
var jsondata = {},
    folders = [{"name" : "test1"}, {"name" : "test1"}, {"name" : "test2"}],
    actions = [{"id": "2"}, {"id":"4"}];

jsondata["month"] = "01";
jsondata["folders"] = folders;
jsondata["actions"] = actions;

console.log(jsondata);
```

Comment: You're right, thanks, but why ? What is the correct structure to get month whith "JsonData.month;" ?

Comment: Right it's because I use ".push({'name':'test1'})" What's the correct way ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: There is no correct way.. It depends on how you want to store and retrieve data.

Comment: Yes, I want to store it in the notation that I have written would have worked.. Thank you so much !

Comment: Do you know how to "push" data in order to get : var jsondata = { "month"  : "01",
                 "month1" : "02",
                 "month1" : "02" 
               } ?? Thanks, thanks, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your json string is wrapped in an array

```
JsonData[0].month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get month and the others keys as an array

```
JsonData[0]['month'];
```

or as an object

```
JsonData[0].month;
```